# Possible to send attachment from Unix to Outlook with long lines?

Tags: email, unix, outlook, sendmail, email-attachments

I'm trying to send an email with a csv attachment from a Unix box to a recipient who is using Outlook 2010. The csv has very long lines (approx. 2000 - 3000 characters).

The file is fine on Unix but when the recipient receives the file there are extra exclamation marks(!) and new lines approx every 1000 characters. Here is some example code I've tried:

```
outputFile="/tmp/testemail" 
attachFile="/tmp/test.csv"
(
echo "From: sender@somedomain.com" 
echo "To: receipent@someotherdomain.com"
echo "Subject: Test"
echo "Mime-Version: 1.0"
echo 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="GvXjxJ+pjyke8COw"'
echo "Content-Disposition: inline" 
echo "" 
echo "--GvXjxJ+pjyke8COw" 
echo "Content-Type: text/plain"
echo "Content-Disposition: inline"
cat $outputFile
echo "" 
echo "--GvXjxJ+pjyke8COw"
echo "Content-Type: text/csv"
echo "Content-Disposition: attachement; filename=test.csv"
echo "" 
cat $attachFile
) | /usr/lib/sendmail -t
```

I've also tried going through the different types of content-transfer-encoding listed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Transfer-Encoding. But none seemed to help.

Comment: I would try to open the csv file in excel directly -- if it doesn't work either there's maybe sth. wrong with it (0x0a vs. 0x0d0a?). If it works, send an email with the csv file attached from outlook to yourself and if that works too, try to compare that mail with the one you have generated

Comment: I've done that, I've tried sending in Unix/DOS format, opening in Notepad / Excel. Sending the file to myself in Outlook works fine, I try to compare the mails but when I save down the message Outlook has a very weird format of saving and I just see a lot of binary stuff and not my original message format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sendmail breaks long lines (>990 chars) send over SMTP -> you should send the files using quoted-printable encoding. You may use e.g. `qprint` program for conversion.

quoted-printable encoding handle "too long" lines.
You may also consider specifying charset used (e.g. ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8) or US-ASCII will be assumed as default.

```
...
echo "Mime-Version: 1.0"
echo "Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8"
echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable"
echo "Content-Disposition: attachement; filename=test.csv"
echo "" 
qprint -e $attachFile
...
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the answer but I don't have access to any other tool that sends SMTP

Comment: Could you name Unix/Linux distribution you use? It may help to provide useful hints.

Comment: Solaris 10 is what I'm using at the moment